# Compute t-test for two tables with N/A

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two tables of data. Each table has the same dimension 245x10. The original file can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/gccerbellumfinal). I need to compute t-test for these two tables; however, I get the error when I apply numpy function.

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('GC Cerbellum final.txt', sep='\t')
df1 = df.ix[:, 1:12]
df2 = df.ix[:, 12:]
st.ttest_ind(df1, df2)
```

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in
>   var(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims)    2936     2937     return
>   _methods._var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
>   -> 2938                                 keepdims=keepdims)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.pyc in
>   _var(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims)
>        93     if isinstance(arrmean, mu.ndarray):
>        94         arrmean = um.true_divide(
>   ---> 95                 arrmean, rcount, out=arrmean, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
>        96     else:
>        97         arrmean = arrmean.dtype.type(arrmean / rcount)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

I checked, and it looks that all data is integers and I'm not sure why it fails on strings. It can also be the case that because missing values are filled somehow with strings, it fails.

So my question how can I perform t-test for two tables in python with missing values?

Answer (score 1):

Your file has NAs in it, but pandas does not know how to interpret them. You can read it like

```
df = pd.read_csv('GC Cerbellum final.txt', sep='\t', na_values=[' NA'])
```

and pandas will read them as float columns rather than string columns, with NaNs appropriately.

(By the way, also, your slices don't seem to be right.)

Comment: You broke it up into a group of 11 columns and a group of 9 columns as far as I can tell. (There are a total of 21 columns as far as I can tell, with you not taking the first column, the name of the compound, at all.) Did you mean 10 and 10?